# Extract out first element of list while scraping html tables with rvest

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I've successfully harvested a table from this [webpage](http://mcsafetyfeed.org/incidents.php?date=2019-03-19) using the below `rvest` code:

```
march19 <- read_html("http://mcsafetyfeed.org/incidents.php?date=2019-03-19")

march19_df <- march19 %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table(header = TRUE)
```

*If you have 2 seconds, please run this code to extract out table (`march19_df`). Instead of posting the dput of the table, which is like 1 million lines, I'd rather save the reader's eyes*

The resulting table is a list of 1 element, which includes the table as a dataframe. I'd like to extract out this element, and have tried this to no avail:

`march19_df %>% map(1)`

This simply gives me all the dates, whereas I want to extract the dataframe from the list.

Comment: Maybe add `%>% magrittr::extract2(1)` to the end?

Comment: Or `%>% \`[[\`(1)` , or `%>% pluck(1)` which i find is less typing (pluck is in purrr so I usually have it loaded, as opposed to magrittr which I rarely do)

Comment: `%>% `[[`(1)` worked! But, `pluck` doesn't work...I wonder if there is a function that does `%>% `[[`(1)` @CalumYou...Actually, I just tried @joran 's solution and it works too!

Comment: Or `%>% as.data.frame()` should also work

Comment: `magrittr::extract2()` is exactly `\`[[\`()`, but `purrr::pluck()` is slightly different. Do you have `purrr` installed and attached?

Comment: @CalumYou Oh that's interesting. I tried `purrr::pluck(1)` and it works too!